# Run pgrouting 1.x and 2.x on same machine

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.1, pgrouting

We want to run pgrouting 2.x on our test server. Additionally, we want existing applications still run on pgrouting 1.x.
Does anyone know, if it's possible installing and running them in parallel?

Currently, we run on Postgres 9.1.9 and PostGIS 2.0.1.

Comment: Ideally you'd use two separate PostgreSQL server instances, one with pgrouting 1.x, one with 2.x. Though it might be OK to simply use them in different databases so long as the shared library name is different, as PostgreSQL will only load them when they're actually used by a given database connection.

Comment: So, don't you think it is possible to have it work in one database, just because the function names seem to have changed (e.g. pgr_astar() instead of shortest_path_astar()?

Comment: I suspect the *C extension libraries* may conflict. But I haven't tested - try it and see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not think you can do this for the same postgresql version because both versions use a shared library file librouting.so and this file is not compatible between the old and new versions of pgrouting. If you install Postgresql 9.1 and 9.2 for example then you can install pgrouting 1.x on 9.1 and pgrouting 2.x on 9.2 without a problem. In hind sight, maybe I should have done a better job of change the file names to avoid this, but I didn't so its not going to work.

Also I do not think pgrouting 1.x will work with PostGIS 2.0.1 because they removed a lot of functions that pgrouting 1.x uses. It might be possible to solve this problem if you load the PostGIS legacy.sql file.

Comment: Ok thank you all. I didn't make the effort to test this actually if the prominent idea is, that this won't work. We're now going to test pgrouting 2.x locally and probably making an update if that shows up fine.